# Is there a word that describes the emotion of feeling betrayed?

Tags: single-word-requests

Context: there was a prompt in Health class, and it went as follows: "If you are a victim of hate crimes, you might feel..."

My list of answers went as follows:

- Anger
- Hurt
- Fear
- Betrayal

However, betrayal is not an emotion. It doesn't fit in with the other words on my list. So I need a word that describes the emotion of feeling betrayed.

Comment: Note that there is a difference in your example and the others. So 'angry' (adjective, one word) has the one-word noun form 'anger'. But 'felt betrayed' is a verb phrase, not an adjective, and it has more than one word. So to convert to a noun form you would say "she felt betrayal". (betrayal is the noun form of betrayed).

Comment: It's 'betrayal'.

Answer (score 1):

> She felt betrayed.
> → She experienced **betrayal**.

From Merriam-Webster's [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/betrayal) of the noun:

> **1** : the act of betraying someone or something or the fact of being betrayed : violation of a person's trust or confidence, of a moral standard, etc.
>
> // the *betrayal* of a friend
> // a *betrayal* of trust
> // a *betrayal* of one's principles
>
> **2** : revelation of something hidden or secret
> // a *betrayal* of one's true feelings
> // There was never doubt, never a *betrayal* of indecision.
> — Jack London

---

Note that the noun form of *sad* is *sadness*, not *sorrow*. They are synonymous but they come from different root words.